# REST API Call works on Java but not on Android (FileNotFound)

Tags: java, android, api, rest, asynchronous

In my Android application, I am making an asynchronous call to a database to fetch sports feeds (following the API documentation in this link: https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/data-feeds/api-docs/ (navigate to the "Seasonal Games" section)).

Below is my Android code (exact same as the Java code that I launched in Eclipse, which returned me the correct data):

```
// Launch an API request to MySportsFeeds to retrieve the schedule for NBA matches
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v2.1/pull/nfl/current/games.json");
    String encoding = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("[I_PUT_THE_CORRECT_API_KEY_HERE]:MYSPORTSFEEDS".getBytes());

    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
    InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
        
    String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

That gives me the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v2.1/pull/nfl/current/games.json

This seems strange, considering that the Android and Java code are absolutely identical and I have enabled the relevant permissions in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I tried this and it worked!!

```
String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString("user:password".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Because you are encoding on android try `Base64.NO_WRAP` in your encode method on android.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line: `connection.setDoOutput(true);` resolved the issue for me.